# Null coalescing operator vs. value()

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator

I'm creating some objects to return to a form via API, and the objects are derived from database values, including values that could be null in the database, but cannot be null in the context of my API (I am obtaining data from multiple tables, so I know that if a field is null in one table, I can obtain a legitimate value from another table):

```
List<ResultsByLineShiftSlot> returnResults = new List<ResultsByLineShiftSlot>();
            foreach (LineShiftSlot ls in db.LineShiftSlots.OrderBy(ls => ls.ScheduledDateAndTime).Where(ls => ls.ProductionDate == slotDate &&
                ls.ShiftId == shiftId &&
                ls.LineId == lineId &&
                ls.Quantity > 0 &&
                ls.BlendId != null))
            {
                var recordedResult = db.LineShiftSlotResults.FirstOrDefault(r => r.LineShiftSlotId == ls.Id);
                if (recordedResult != null)
                {
                    ResultsByLineShiftSlot returnResult = new ResultsByLineShiftSlot
                    {

                        BlendId = recordedResult.BlendId

                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    ResultsByLineShiftSlot returnResult = new ResultsByLineShiftSlot
                    {

                        BlendId = ls.BlendId ?? 0

                    };

                }
            }
            return returnResults;
```

In the above example, BlendId can be null in LineShiftSlots, but not in LineShiftSlotResults.

In this context where a nullable variable is known to contain a non-null value, which is better?

Should I use the null coalescing operator:

```
BlendId = ls.BlendId ?? 0
```

Or should I use .Value():

```
BlendId = ls.BlendId.value()
```

Both compile, and seem to work.

Are they functionally equivalent in this context?  Is using one over the other better practice?  I know that .value() could potentially return an exception, whereas the null coalescing operator could not, but in this case .value can never be null.

Comment: Why not just `labelId = recordValue.labelId ?? otherValue`? However in general, if you 'know' the value is not-null you should use `.Value` since that will raise an exception if your assertion is wrong, while the null-coalescing operator will hide that fact and silently give you the wrong value.

Comment: If you are certain that `FirstOrDefault` will return a value, use `First`, otherwise you should check `recordValue` for `null` as well.

Comment: And if you are going to use `Value`, I would suggest perhaps pairing it with `HasValue` instead of a `null` comparison.

Comment: @crashmstr The recordset may or may not be null in my actual code (I'll add a better example in a minute).  Whether the recordset is null or not determines which source I'll be using to populate the return object.

Comment: @Lee If the recordset is null, then I pull from a different data source.  I've added a fuller example to illustrate.  The point about using `.Value` in order to raise an error is kind of the gist of what I was asking, although in the simplified example of `if (someValue != null) { nullableVariable = someValue.Value(); }` could clearly never trigger that particular exception.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, they're not semantically equivalent.

```
labelId = recordValue.labelId.Value;
```

This one means **I know the value can't be `null`. Just throw if my assumption is wrong**.

On the other hand,

```
labelId = recordValue.labelId ?? 0;
labelId = recordValue.labelId.GetValueOrDefault();
```

These two mean that the value *may* be null, and if that happens, just ignore it, considering it's normal, and substitute it with the default value.

I'd use `GetValueOrDefault()` in that case, it makes it somewhat more obvious (and the JIT will inline this method).

---

However, your code is equivalent to this simpler alternative:

```
labelId = recordValue.labelId ?? otherValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case the code would be the same however have you considered the following

```
labelId = recordValue.labelId ?? otherValue
```

which is essentially the following

```
if(recordValue.labelId != null){
    labelId = recordValue.labelId.Value;
}
else
{
    labelId = otherValue;
}
```